# 日本語に違和感: 金バッジ「すばらしい」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

金バッジ"fanatic"の訳語「すばらしい」は、本来の意図からするとおかしな語になっています。

類似バッジの"enthusiast"は「[熱狂者](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast)」としていますから、"fanatic"は「[すばらしい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic)」ではなく、「熱狂的ファン」「狂信者」などがよいでしょうか？

Comment: バッジ全体を見直す必要があると思います。提案があれば、どんどん提案してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「狂信者」に変換しました。

もっといい提案があれば、ご教示下さい。

Comment: enthusiastとfanaticの2つとも同じ「熱狂者」になってしまいますが、そこは問題ないのでしょうか？

Comment: @yohjp そうですか・・・問題ですね。「狂信者」に更新しました。ちゃんと日本語読まなくてすみません！