# バッジ名の日本語訳

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, バッジ

バッジの名称についてですが、全体的に直訳調で意味が伝わりにくいので、日本語化を考えたいと思っております。

関連トピック：  
[日本語に違和感: 「識者」バッジ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E8%AD%98%E8%80%85-%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8)  
[日本語に違和感：バッジ「子鹿」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8-%E5%AD%90%E9%B9%BF)  
[バッジの説明の日本語訳](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%B3)  
[バッジの分析的について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)  
[日本語に違和感: 金バッジ「すばらしい」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/178/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E9%87%91%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8-%E3%81%99%E3%81%B0%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)

バッジと現在の訳

```
Altruist    利他主義者
Benefactor    後援者
Curious    興味
Inquisitive    探求的
Socratic    ソクラテス式
Favorite Question    お気に入りの質問
Stellar Question    すごい質問
Investor    投資家
Nice Question    ナイスな質問
Good Question    良い質問
Great Question    優れた質問
Popular Question    人気のある質問
Notable Question    注目に値する質問
Famous Question    有名な質問
Promoter    プロモーター
Scholar    学者
Student    生徒
Tumbleweed    閑古鳥
Enlightened    悟り
Explainer    （未訳）
Refiner    （未訳）
Illuminator    （未訳）
Generalist    博識
Guru    師匠
Nice Answer    ナイスな回答
Good Answer    良い回答
Great Answer    優れた回答
Populist    大衆主義者
Reversal    取り消し
Revival    リバイバル
Necromancer    霊媒
Self-Learner    独学者
Teacher    先生
Tenacious    粘り強い
Unsung Hero    陰の英雄
Autobiographer    自伝作家
Caucus    党員集会
Constituent    有権者
Commentator    コメンテーター
Pundit    評論家
Enthusiast    熱狂者
Fanatic    狂信者
Mortarboard    角帽
Epic    大作
Legendary    伝説
Precognitive    予知
Beta    ベータ
Quorum    選抜
Convention    会議
Talkative    饒舌
Outspoken    率直
Yearling    子鹿
(Bronze Badge)    銅バッジ
(Silver Badge)    銀バッジ
(Gold Badge)    金バッジ
Citizen Patrol    市民パトロール
Deputy    副官
Marshal    連邦保安官
Civic Duty    市民の義務
Cleanup    クリーンアップ
Constable    巡査
Sheriff    保安官
Critic    批評家
Custodian    守衛
Reviewer    レビュー担当者
Steward    執事
Disciplined    規律
Editor    編集者
Strunk & White    文法の達人
Copy Editor    コピー編集者
Electorate    選挙人
Excavator    穴掘人
Archaeologist    考古学者
Organizer    まとめ役
Peer Pressure    周囲からの圧力
Proofreader    校正者
Sportsmanship    スポーツマン精神
Suffrage    投票権
Supporter    サポーター
Synonymizer    シノニム マニア
Tag Editor    タグ編集者
Research Assistant    調査助手
Taxonomist    分類学者
Vox Populi    大衆の声
Analytical    分析的
Announcer    アナウンサー
Booster    支援者
Publicist    評論家
Informed    理解者
```

Comment: バッジ名を集めたら、一括で適用するつもりです（少しずつ反映すると管理が難しくなり、作業が何倍ぐらいの時間になってしまいます）。まとめてくれてありがとうございます！

Comment: @jmac 珍しいバッジ(tumbleweed：タンブルウィード)を付けた人を見かけたので意味が気になり調べましたが、回答にあるように「閑古鳥」にした方が日本人には分かりやすいです。単にタンブルウィードだと日本ではほとんど理解されません。tumbleweedだけが飛び抜けて分かりにくいです。

Comment: @kotatsu 更新しました、ありがとうございます。適用には時間がかかりますが、投稿では更新しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

長らく放置していて申し訳ありませんが、バッジ名更新案をとりまとめたいと思います。以下のリストは前の回答の中から独断で選んだものなので、ご意見などあればコメントお願いします。

---

これで提出しようと思います。ご協力ありがとうございました。

```
## 質問バッジ

Altruist           篤志家
-- 別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した

Benefactor         賛助者
-- 自分自身の質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した

Curious            好奇心
Inquisitive        探求心
Socratic           研究熱心
-- (5/30/100) の異なる日で評判のよい質問をし、ポジティブな質問履歴を維持していた

Favorite Question  保存版
Stellar Question   永久保存版
-- (25/100) 人のユーザーがお気に入りに追加した質問

Investor           スポンサー
-- 別のユーザーの質問に初めてお礼を提示した

Nice Question      いい質問
Good Question      すごい質問
Great Question     会心の質問
-- 質問スコアが (10/25/100) 以上 

Popular Question   人気の質問
Notable Question   注目の質問
Famous Question    有名な質問
-- 投稿した質問が (1000/2500/10000) 回閲覧された

Promoter           自己PR
-- 自分自身の質問に初めてお礼を提示した

Scholar            学者
-- 質問をして回答を承認した

Student            生徒
-- 初めてスコア 1 以上を得る質問をした

Tumbleweed         閑古鳥
-- 質問をしたが投票されず、回答がなく、コメントがなく、その週の閲覧が少なかった

## 回答バッジ

Enlightened        ひらめき
-- 最初に回答してスコア 10 以上で承認された

Explainer          添削者
Refiner            指南家
Illuminator        赤ペン先生
-- 編集かつ回答した質問が (1/50/500) 個以上 (編集と回答は 12 時間以内であること、また回答の得票数は 1 以上であること)

Generalist         博識
-- トップの 40 個のタグのうち 20 個で合計スコア 15 の wiki 以外の回答を投稿した

Guru               師匠
-- 回答が承認され、スコア 40 以上を獲得した

Nice Answer        いい回答
Good Answer        すごい回答
Great Answer       会心の回答
-- 回答スコアが (10/25/100) 以上

Populist           みんなが選んだ
-- 承認された回答を超える最高スコアを獲得し、それがスコア 10 より大きく、2 倍以上だった

Reversal           仇取り
-- スコアが -5 の質問に +20 の回答をした

Revival            蘇生術
-- 質問投稿後 30 日以上たってから最初の回答を投稿し、スコア 2 以上を獲得した

Necromancer        復活の呪文
-- 質問投稿後 60 日以上たってから回答し、スコアが 5 以上

Self-Learner       蛍の光
-- スコア 3 以上の自分の質問に回答した

Teacher            先生
-- 初めてスコア 1 以上を得る回答をした

Tenacious          不屈の精神
Unsung Hero        陰の英雄
-- スコア 0 の承認された回答が (5/10) 個以上あり、かつ合計の (20/25)% を超える

## 参加バッジ

Autobiographer     初めまして
-- プロフィールの「自分について」欄を埋めた

Caucus             集会場
-- モデレーター選挙期間中に、投票に必要な信用度がある状態で選挙ページを訪問した

Constituent        有権者
-- モデレーター選挙の最終段階で候補者に投票した

Commentator        コメンテーター
-- 10 件のコメントを投稿した

Pundit             ご意見番
-- スコア 5 以上のコメントを 10 件投稿した

Enthusiast         精勤賞
Fanatic            皆勤賞
-- 30,100 日間毎日サイトを訪問した

Mortarboard        秀才
Epic               異才
Legendary          鬼才
-- 1 日で 200 点 (1 日の最大値) 以上の信用度を獲得したことが (1/50/150) 回あった

Precognitive       先見の明
-- このサイトが参加表明の段階に入る前に、エリア 51 での設立提案をフォローした

Beta               ベータ
-- プライベートベータに積極的に参加した

Quorum             メタ発言
Convention         メタナイト
-- メタで、スコアが 2 以上の投稿が (1/10) 件ある

Talkative          多弁
-- 10 件以上のメッセージをチャットで投稿し、そのうちの 1 件以上がお気に入りに登録された

Outspoken          能弁
-- 10 件以上のメッセージをチャットで投稿し、そのうちの 10 件が別々のユーザーのお気に入りに登録された

Yearling           年輪
-- 1 年間アクティブなメンバーで、200 点以上の信用度を獲得した

## タグバッジ

(Bronze Badge)     銅バッジ
(Silver Badge)     銀バッジ
(Gold Badge)       金バッジ

## モデレーション バッジ

Citizen Patrol     自警団
-- 初めて投稿を通報した

Deputy             感謝状
Marshal            顕彰状
-- 有益な通報を (80/500) 回以上行った

Civic Duty         市民の務め
-- 300 回以上投票した

Cleanup            美化委員
-- 初めてのロールバック

Constable          守人
--  1 年以上、またはサイトの昇格まで暫定モデレーターの役目を果たした

Sheriff            保安官
-- モデレーターに選挙で当選し、モデレーターの任務を 1 年以上果たした

Critic             物申す
-- 初めての反対投票

Custodian          見回り
Reviewer           宿直
Steward            支配人
-- レビュー タスクを (1/250/1000) 件以上完了した

Disciplined        完璧主義
-- スコアが 3 以上の自分の投稿を削除した

Editor             編集者
-- 投稿を初めて編集した
Strunk & White     校閲者
-- 80 件の投稿を編集した
Copy Editor        編集王
-- 500 件の投稿を編集した（自分の投稿、削除された投稿、またタグのみの編集を除く）

Electorate         鑑識眼
-- 600 件の質問に投票していて、合計投票数の 25% 以上が質問に対するものである

Excavator          発掘家
Archaeologist      考古学者
--  6 か月間非アクティブだった投稿を (1/100) 件編集した

Organizer          整理整頓
-- 質問のタグを初めて付け直した

Peer Pressure      察する力
-- スコアが -3 以下の自分の投稿を削除した

Proofreader        校正大臣
-- 提案された 100 件の編集内容を承認または却下した

Sportsmanship      スポーツマンシップ
-- 自分が回答した質問への他の人の回答に 100 回プラス投票した (自分の回答のスコアが 1 以上である場合に限る)

Suffrage           投票日
--  1 日で 30 票を投じた

Supporter          ファン
-- 初めてのプラス投票

Synonymizer        想像力
-- 提案したタグシノニムが初めて承認された

Tag Editor         図書委員
Research Assistant 司書
-- タグ wiki を (1/50) 件編集した

Taxonomist         分類学者
-- 作成したタグが 50 個の質問で使用された

Vox Populi         総選挙
-- 1 日の最大投票数 40 票を全て投じた

## その他のバッジ

Analytical         （いらない？）
-- FAQ の全項目を閲覧した ( FAQ ページがなくなったので現在は終了)

Announcer          呼び込み
Booster            宣伝部
Publicist          広報大使
-- リンクをシェアした質問が (25/300/1000) 個の異なる IP アドレスからアクセスされた

Informed           準備万端
-- ツアーを全部読んだ
```

Comment: "Popular Question"は「人気の質問」の方がよい気がします。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。「良くある質問」だと違う意味になりかねないですし、直しておきます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: こちらの回答を承認しておくと、既に票を集めてしまっているWiki回答より上に表示されて目立つかと（今更ですが）

Comment: @unarist 確かにそれはうまい使い方ですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

叩き台を出します。Wiki化してあるので大喜利大会にして構いません。

```
## 質問バッジ

Altruist           篤志家 慈善家 寄付 赤い羽根
-- 別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した

Benefactor         賛助者 パトロン 後援者
-- 自分自身の質問に初めて手動でお礼を授与した

Curious            好奇心
Inquisitive        探求心
Socratic           無知の知 学究心 希哲心 研究熱心
-- (5/30/100) の異なる日で評判のよい質問をし、ポジティブな質問履歴を維持していた

Favorite Question  保存版
Stellar Question   永久保存版
-- (25/100) 人のユーザーがお気に入りに追加した質問

Investor           投資家 スポンサー
-- 別のユーザーの質問に初めてお礼を提示した

Nice Question      質問・銅メダル いい質問
Good Question      質問・銀メダル  すごい質問
Great Question     質問・金メダル 会心の質問
-- 質問スコアが (10/25/100) 以上 

Popular Question   知名度・銅メダル 良くある質問
Notable Question   知名度・銀メダル 注目の質問
Famous Question    知名度・金メダル 有名な質問
-- 投稿した質問が (1000/2500/10000) 回閲覧された

Promoter           スポンサー 自己PR
-- 自分自身の質問に初めてお礼を提示した

Scholar            学者 学徒
-- 質問をして回答を承認した

Student            生徒
-- 初めてスコア 1 以上を得る質問をした

Tumbleweed         人知れずこそ 閑古鳥
-- 質問をしたが投票されず、回答がなく、コメントがなく、その週の閲覧が少なかった

## 回答バッジ

Enlightened        明哲 教授 ひらめき
-- 最初に回答してスコア 10 以上で承認された

Explainer          説明者 説明家 添削者
Refiner            論客 指南家
Illuminator        啓蒙家 赤ペン先生
-- 編集かつ回答した質問が (1/50/500) 個以上 (編集と回答は 12 時間以内であること、また回答の得票数は 1 以上であること)

Generalist         博識
-- トップの 40 個のタグのうち 20 個で合計スコア 15 の wiki 以外の回答を投稿した

Guru               師匠
-- 回答が承認され、スコア 40 以上を獲得した

Nice Answer        回答・銅メダル いい回答
Good Answer        回答・銀メダル すごい回答
Great Answer       回答・金メダル 会心の回答
-- 回答スコアが (10/25/100) 以上

Populist           みんなが選んだ 人気者
-- 承認された回答を超える最高スコアを獲得し、それがスコア 10 より大きく、2 倍以上だった

Reversal           名誉挽回 仇取り エース 逆転サヨナラ
-- スコアが -5 の質問に +20 の回答をした

Revival            蘇生術
-- 質問投稿後 30 日以上たってから最初の回答を投稿し、スコア 2 以上を獲得した

Necromancer        復活の呪文
-- 質問投稿後 60 日以上たってから回答し、スコアが 5 以上

Self-Learner       独学者 蛍の光 窓の雪
-- スコア 3 以上の自分の質問に回答した

Teacher            先生
-- 初めてスコア 1 以上を得る回答をした

Tenacious          不屈の精神
Unsung Hero        陰の英雄
-- スコア 0 の承認された回答が (5/10) 個以上あり、かつ合計の (20/25)% を超える

## 参加バッジ

Autobiographer     自分史 自己紹介 初めまして
-- プロフィールの「自分について」欄を埋めた

Caucus             選挙部 集会場
-- モデレーター選挙期間中に、投票に必要な信用度がある状態で選挙ページを訪問した

Constituent        有権者
-- モデレーター選挙の最終段階で候補者に投票した

Commentator        解説者 コメンテーター
-- 10 件のコメントを投稿した

Pundit             名解説 ご意見番
-- スコア 5 以上のコメントを 10 件投稿した

Enthusiast         精勤賞
Fanatic            皆勤賞
-- 30,100 日間毎日サイトを訪問した

Mortarboard        秀才
Epic               天才 異才
Legendary          鬼才
-- 1 日で 200 点 (1 日の最大値) 以上の信用度を獲得したことが (1/50/150) 回あった

Precognitive       予知 第六感 虫の知らせ 先見の明
-- このサイトが参加表明の段階に入る前に、エリア 51 での設立提案をフォローした

Beta               ベータ
-- プライベートベータに積極的に参加した

Quorum             メタ発言 発議
Convention         メタナイト 熟議
-- メタで、スコアが 2 以上の投稿が (1/10) 件ある

Talkative          多弁
-- 10 件以上のメッセージをチャットで投稿し、そのうちの 1 件以上がお気に入りに登録された

Outspoken          能弁
-- 10 件以上のメッセージをチャットで投稿し、そのうちの 10 件が別々のユーザーのお気に入りに登録された

Yearling           年輪 年の功
-- 1 年間アクティブなメンバーで、200 点以上の信用度を獲得した

## タグバッジ

(Bronze Badge)     銅バッジ
(Silver Badge)     銀バッジ
(Gold Badge)       金バッジ

## モデレーション バッジ

Citizen Patrol     自警団
-- 初めて投稿を通報した

Deputy             感謝状
Marshal            顕彰状
-- 有益な通報を (80/500) 回以上行った

Civic Duty         善悪の彼岸 市民の務め
-- 300 回以上投票した

Cleanup            掃除人 美化委員
-- 初めてのロールバック

Constable          守人
--  1 年以上、またはサイトの昇格まで暫定モデレーターの役目を果たした

Sheriff            保安官
-- モデレーターに選挙で当選し、モデレーターの任務を 1 年以上果たした

Critic             物申す
-- 初めての反対投票

Custodian          見回り
Reviewer           宿直
Steward            支配人
-- レビュー タスクを (1/250/1000) 件以上完了した

Disciplined        完璧主義
-- スコアが 3 以上の自分の投稿を削除した

Editor             編集者
-- 投稿を初めて編集した
Strunk & White     校閲者
-- 80 件の投稿を編集した
Copy Editor        編集王
-- 500 件の投稿を編集した（自分の投稿、削除された投稿、またタグのみの編集を除く）

Electorate         鑑識眼 閻魔大王
-- 600 件の質問に投票していて、合計投票数の 25% 以上が質問に対するものである

Excavator          発掘家
Archaeologist      考古学者
--  6 か月間非アクティブだった投稿を (1/100) 件編集した

Organizer          交通整理 整理整頓
-- 質問のタグを初めて付け直した

Peer Pressure      察する力 周囲の圧力
-- スコアが -3 以下の自分の投稿を削除した

Proofreader        校正者 校正大臣
-- 提案された 100 件の編集内容を承認または却下した

Sportsmanship      敵ながらあっぱれ リスペクト スポーツマンシップ
-- 自分が回答した質問への他の人の回答に 100 回プラス投票した (自分の回答のスコアが 1 以上である場合に限る)

Suffrage           明るい選挙 投票日
--  1 日で 30 票を投じた

Supporter          ファン 太鼓判 清き一票
-- 初めてのプラス投票

Synonymizer        想像力 辞書編纂
-- 提案したタグシノニムが初めて承認された

Tag Editor         図書委員
Research Assistant 司書 生き字引
-- タグ wiki を (1/50) 件編集した

Taxonomist         分類学者
-- 作成したタグが 50 個の質問で使用された

Vox Populi         総選挙 世論
-- 1 日の最大投票数 40 票を全て投じた

## その他のバッジ

Analytical         （いらない？）
-- FAQ の全項目を閲覧した ( FAQ ページがなくなったので現在は終了)

Announcer          呼び込み
Booster            宣伝部
Publicist          広報大使
-- リンクをシェアした質問が (25/300/1000) 個の異なる IP アドレスからアクセスされた

Informed           理解者 準備万端 駆け出し
-- ツアーを全部読んだ
```

Comment: ソクラテスは哲学者でしたっけ？
何かと職業に結びついている方がわかりやすいかと…

Comment: ソクラテスは哲学者で、町に出ていろんな人に問いをぶつけたことで有名な人です。そういう感じのニュアンスが出ればいいのですが…

Comment: なるほど、思い出しました**無知の知**というやつですね

Comment: あっそれいいですね。直接編集できます？

Comment: Wikiの編集は信用度が100点以上必要？なようです。。メタサイトでは、タグwikiでない投稿の編集を推奨することはできません。と表示されています。

Comment: なるほど、Wikiといえども最初から書き込めるわけではないんですね…。失礼しました、反映しておきます。

Comment: 「メタナイト」って何ですか? サムソナイト、メタの騎士?

Comment: @ento http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%83%8A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88 これとかけたつもりなのですが、やっぱりわかりづらいですかね…。あと、説明文の追加ありがとうございます。確かに説明の方も直さないといけないの多いですね。名称案もセンスにあふれてます。

Comment: 編集履歴を見るといくつか消された案があるのですが(閑古鳥など)なるべく残したほうが良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @broccoliforest 腰を据えて遊んだことがなくて分かりませんでした :) 知らない人にも「メタ+ナイト」でなんとなくの意味合いは出ているので、ちょっと謎めいた名前でもよいとは思います。

Comment: @h2so5 自分が出した案は自分自身でもっといいものを思いつけば消してもいいと思ってましたが、一応残しておくべきでしょうかね…

Comment: 少なくとも閑古鳥についてはかなり良いと思いました

Comment: ありがとうございます^^。何があるかわからないのでとりあえず全部復活させておきます。というかwiki化してあるので100点以上あればどなたでも編集できますよ？

Comment: ソクラテスが「哲学の祖」と呼ばれること、「哲学」が「希哲学」（賢哲を希求する学問）の省略であることを考えると、もし「○○心」で合わせたいなら「希哲心」とかどうでしょう？　普通使われない言葉なので伝わらない可能性が有りますが……。同じく編集できないのでここに書かせていただきました。